# How to keep hover effect with div

Tags: jquery, css, html, hover, effects

I have a problem width a hover effect on images
When the cursor is over an image link, a yellow div is coming on the image // it works

the yellow div disappear's when the cursor leave the image //ok

What I want to do :
when the image is clicked, it calls the second page (ok), BUT when you came back to the first page, the image is already with the yellow div on
(like it keeps the hover effect, and this for every image clicked)

I'm completly lost !

my code :

```css
.slick {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -khtml-transition:  all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:    all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition:      all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition:         all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.projet-container { 
    position:relative; 
    display:block; 
    margin:2px; 
}               
.projet-titre { 
    position:absolute; 
    display:block; 
    top:0;  
    height:184px; 
    width:184px; 
    opacity:0; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
}
.titre { 
    display:block; 
    padding:0px 20px; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    margin:30px 0px 0px 0px; 
    font-size:1.2em; 
    line-height:1.3em;
}           
.projet-container a { 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
}
.projet-container a:hover .projet-titre, .projet-container a:focus .projet-titre { 
    opacity:1; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
    background:#ffff00 url(img/projet-hover.png) no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size:cover; 
    -moz-background-size:cover; 
    -o-background-size:cover; 
    background-size:cover; 
    width:184px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="projet-container">
    <a href="2.html">
        <img  src="urbanisme.gif">                          
        <div class="projet-titre slick">
            <span class="titre">lorem ipsum</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>        
<div class="projet-container">
    <a href="2.html">
        <img  src="1_logement.gif">                           
        <div class="projet-titre slick">
            <span class="titre">lorem ipsum</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing ".projet-container a:focus .projet-titre" from your css?

Comment: Try removing focus on the element. And also can u create a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thank's for the quick answers, it doesn't work if I remove the focus : http://www.jard-brychcy-architecture.fr/temp/color3.html

Comment: On linux chrome it works: if then i click on back link, div is not yellow. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using safari 4.1.3 OSX.If, when you click "back", the image isn't with the yellow div, it doesn't work.this is the all problem.thank's anyway